# Postfix: Virtual users can't receive external e-mails

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, dovecot, cyrus

I'm new to postfix. Sending e-mails works fine, but I can't receive external e-mails. ERR:User not found.Here are my configs. What's wrong?

### System

Centos7.1 x64 (Conoha's image)

### Software

postfix 3.1.1 (Compiled by myself)

```
make makefiles shared=yes shlib_directory=/usr/local/lib/postfix/3.1.1 dynamicmaps=yes 'CCARGS=-DHAS_MYSQL -I/usr/include/mysql -DUSE_SASL_AUTH -DDEF_SERVER_SASL_TYPE=\"dovecot\" ' 'AUXLIBS_MYSQL=-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lm'
```

dovecot 2.2.10 (yum)

cyrus-sasl 2.1.26(yum)

cyrus-imapd* 2.4.17(yum)

postfixadmin 2.93 (Downloaded from sf.net)

MariaDB 10.1.16 (yum)

nginx 1.6.3 (yum)

php (yum,disabled some danger functions)

### Networks

Using mydomain123.com instead of the real doname.

Using 123.123.123.123 instead of the real ip.

#### Private networks

192.168.0.1 (255.255.248.0)

10.0.0.1 (255.255.248.0)

#### Public networks

123.123.123.123 (255.255.254.0) (With PTR:mydomain.com)

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 123-123-123-123
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 123-123-123-123
```

hostname 123-123-123-123

#### Open Ports

public
110/tcp 80/tcp 143/tcp 995/tcp 25/tcp 993/tcp 443/tcp 587/tcp 8025/tcp(postfixadmin)

private ALL

### Domain&DNS

Using mydomain123.com instead of the real doname.

Using 123.123.123.123 instead of the real ip.

mydomain123.com

@ A 123.123.123.123

@ MX mail.mydomain123.com

www A 123.123.123.123

mail A 123.123.123.123

pop A 123.123.123.123

pop3 A 123.123.123.123

imap A 123.123.123.123

smtp A 123.123.123.123

### Users

```
groupadd -g 5000 vmail

useradd -g vmail -u 5000 -s /sbin/nologin vmail
```

Others as default.

#### /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
compatibility_level = 2
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = mail.mydomain123.com
mydomain = mydomain123.com
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
local_recipient_maps =
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP unknow
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/local/man
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
readme_directory = no
smtputf8_enable = no
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
smtpd_sasl_application_name = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_sasl_security_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail/
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps =
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf,
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf,
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps =
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf,
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
shlib_directory = /usr/local/lib/postfix/${mail_version}
```

#### /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

#### /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf

```
user = mymaildb
password = mypassword
hosts = localhost
dbname = mymaildb
query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='%s' AND active = '1'
```

#### /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf

```
user = mymaildb
password = mypassword
hosts = localhost
dbname = mymaildb
query = SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and alias.address = CONCAT('%u', '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'
```

#### /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf

```
user = mymaildb
password = mypassword
hosts = localhost
dbname = mymaildb
query = SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and alias.address = CONCAT('@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'
```

#### /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf

```
user = mymaildb
password = mypassword
hosts = localhost
dbname = mymaildb
query = SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='%s' AND active = '1'
```

#### /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

```
user = mymaildb
password = mypassword
hosts = localhost
dbname = mymaildb
query = SELECT maildir FROM mailbox WHERE username='%s' AND active = '1'
```

#### /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf

```
user = mymaildb
password = mypassword
hosts = localhost
dbname = mymaildb
query = SELECT maildir FROM mailbox,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and mailbox.username = CONCAT('%u','@',alias_domain.target_domain) AND mailbox.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'
```

#### /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf

```
user = mymaildb
password = mypassword
hosts = localhost
dbname = mymaildb
query = SELECT quota FROM mailbox WHERE username='%s' AND active = '1'
```

#### /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

```
# 2.2.10: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)  
#log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
#info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-info.log
protocols = imap pop3

listen = *

!include conf.d/*.conf

passdb {

  driver = sql

  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext

}

userdb {

  driver = static

  args = uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/home/vmail/%d/%n

}

#debug log

auth_debug_passwords=yes

mail_debug=yes

auth_verbose=yes

auth_verbose_passwords=plain
```

#### /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth_mechanisms = plain login cram-md5
!include auth-system.conf.ext
```

#### /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf

```
ssl = no
```

#### /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf

```
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
}
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
```

#### /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-logging.conf

```
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-info.log
debug_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-debug.log
plugin {
}
```

#### /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener lmtp {
  }
}
service imap {
}
service pop3 {
}
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
    group = vmail
  }
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service auth-worker {
}
service dict {
  unix_listener dict {
  }
}
```

#### /etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-lda.conf

```
postmaster_address = postmaster@mydomain123.com
protocol lda {
}
```

#### /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext

```
driver = mysql
connect = host=localhost dbname=mymaildb user=mymaildb password=mypassword
userdb_warning_disable=yes
#postfixadmin
default_pass_scheme = MD5-CRYPT
password_query = SELECT username AS user,password FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active='1'
user_query = SELECT CONCAT('/home/vmail/', maildir) AS home, 5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid, CONCAT('*:bytes=', quota) as quota_rule FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active='1'
```

#### postfixadmin config.inc.php

```
<?php

$CONF['configured'] = true;
$CONF['setup_password'] = 'mypasswordhash';
$CONF['default_language'] = 'en';
$CONF['language_hook'] = '';

$CONF['database_type'] = 'mysqli';
$CONF['database_host'] = 'localhost';
$CONF['database_user'] = 'mymaildb';
$CONF['database_password'] = 'mypassword';
$CONF['database_name'] = 'mymaildb';
$CONF['database_prefix'] = '';
$CONF['database_tables'] = array (
    'admin' => 'admin',
    'alias' => 'alias',
    'alias_domain' => 'alias_domain',
    'config' => 'config',
    'domain' => 'domain',
    'domain_admins' => 'domain_admins',
    'fetchmail' => 'fetchmail',
    'log' => 'log',
    'mailbox' => 'mailbox',
    'vacation' => 'vacation',
    'vacation_notification' => 'vacation_notification',
    'quota' => 'quota',
    'quota2' => 'quota2',
);
$CONF['admin_email'] = '';
$CONF['smtp_server'] = 'localhost';
$CONF['smtp_port'] = '25';
$CONF['encrypt'] = 'dovecot:CRAM-MD5';
$CONF['authlib_default_flavor'] = 'md5raw';
$CONF['dovecotpw'] = "/usr/bin/doveadm pw";
$CONF['password_validation'] = array(
#    '/regular expression/' => '$PALANG key (optional: + parameter)',
    '/.{5}/'                => 'password_too_short 5',      # minimum length 5 characters
    '/([a-zA-Z].*){3}/'     => 'password_no_characters 3',  # must contain at least 3 characters
    '/([0-9].*){2}/'        => 'password_no_digits 2',      # must contain at least 2 digits
);
$CONF['generate_password'] = 'NO';
$CONF['show_password'] = 'NO';
$CONF['page_size'] = '10';
$CONF['default_aliases'] = array (
    'abuse' => 'abuse@mydomain123.com',
    'hostmaster' => 'hostmaster@mydomain123.com',
    'postmaster' => 'postmaster@mydomain123.com',
    'webmaster' => 'webmaster@mydomain123.com'
);
$CONF['domain_path'] = 'YES';
$CONF['domain_in_mailbox'] = 'NO';
$CONF['maildir_name_hook'] = 'NO';

$CONF['admin_struct_hook']          = '';
$CONF['domain_struct_hook']         = '';
$CONF['alias_struct_hook']          = '';
$CONF['mailbox_struct_hook']        = '';
$CONF['alias_domain_struct_hook']   = '';
$CONF['fetchmail_struct_hook']      = '';
$CONF['aliases'] = '1000';
$CONF['mailboxes'] = '1000';
$CONF['maxquota'] = '1000';
$CONF['domain_quota_default'] = '2048';
$CONF['quota'] = 'YES';
$CONF['domain_quota'] = 'YES';
$CONF['quota_multiplier'] = '1024000';
$CONF['transport'] = 'NO';
$CONF['transport_options'] = array (
    'virtual',  // for virtual accounts
    'local',    // for system accounts
    'relay'     // for backup mx
);
$CONF['transport_default'] = 'virtual';
$CONF['vacation'] = 'NO';
$CONF['vacation_domain'] = 'autoreply.mydomain123.com';
$CONF['vacation_control'] ='YES';
$CONF['vacation_control_admin'] = 'YES';
$CONF['vacation_choice_of_reply'] = array (
   0 => 'reply_once',        // Sends only Once the message during Out of Office
   # considered annoying - only send a reply on every mail if you really need it
   # 1 => 'reply_every_mail',       // Reply on every email
   60*60 *24*7 => 'reply_once_per_week'        // Reply if last autoreply was at least a week ago
);
$CONF['alias_control'] = 'YES';
$CONF['alias_control_admin'] = 'YES';
$CONF['special_alias_control'] = 'NO';
$CONF['alias_goto_limit'] = '0';
$CONF['alias_domain'] = 'YES';
$CONF['backup'] = 'NO';
$CONF['sendmail'] = 'YES';
$CONF['logging'] = 'YES';
$CONF['fetchmail'] = 'NO';
$CONF['fetchmail_extra_options'] = 'NO';
$CONF['show_header_text'] = 'NO';
$CONF['header_text'] = ':: Postfix Admin ::';
$CONF['show_footer_text'] = 'YES';
$CONF['footer_text'] = 'Return to mydomain123.com';
$CONF['footer_link'] = 'mydomain123.com';
$CONF['motd_user'] = '';
$CONF['motd_admin'] = '';
$CONF['motd_superadmin'] = '';
$CONF['welcome_text'] = <<<EOM
Hi,
Welcome to your new account.
EOM;
$CONF['emailcheck_resolve_domain']='YES';
$CONF['show_status']='YES';
$CONF['show_status_key']='YES';
$CONF['show_status_text']='&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$CONF['show_undeliverable']='YES';
$CONF['show_undeliverable_color']='tomato';
$CONF['show_undeliverable_exceptions']=array("unixmail.domain.ext","exchangeserver.domain.ext");
$CONF['show_popimap']='YES';
$CONF['show_popimap_color']='darkgrey';
$CONF['show_custom_domains']=array("subdomain.domain.ext","domain2.ext");
$CONF['show_custom_colors']=array("lightgreen","lightblue");
$CONF['recipient_delimiter'] = "";
$CONF['mailbox_postcreation_script'] = '';
$CONF['mailbox_postedit_script'] = '';
$CONF['mailbox_postdeletion_script'] = '';
$CONF['domain_postcreation_script'] = '';
$CONF['domain_postdeletion_script'] = '';
$CONF['create_mailbox_subdirs'] = array();
$CONF['create_mailbox_subdirs_host']='localhost';
$CONF['create_mailbox_subdirs_prefix']='INBOX.';
$CONF['used_quotas'] = 'YES';
$CONF['new_quota_table'] = 'YES';
$CONF['create_mailbox_subdirs_hostoptions'] = array('');
$CONF['theme_logo'] = 'images/logo-default.png';
$CONF['theme_css'] = 'css/default.css';
$CONF['theme_custom_css'] = '';
$CONF['xmlrpc_enabled'] = false;
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.local.php')) {
    include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.local.php');
}
/* vim: set expandtab softtabstop=4 tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4: */
```

#### /var/log/maillog [NO errors]

```
localhost postfix/smtpd[31623]: 1077ADEA2: client=unknown[myip], sasl_method=CRAM-MD5, sasl_username=test1@mydomain123.com
localhost postfix/smtpd[31623]: disconnect from unknown[myip] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 quit=1 unknown=0/1 commands=5/6
```

#### /var/log/dovecot.log [NO errors while sending an email,but...]

```
auth: Fatal: master: service(auth): child 30172 killed with signal 11 (core dumped)
lda: Error: userdb lookup(test1@mydomain123.com): Disconnected unexpectedly
lda: Fatal: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
auth: Fatal: master: service(auth): child 30757 killed with signal 11 (core dumped)
auth: Fatal: master: service(auth): child 30976 killed with signal 11 (core dumped)
lda: Error: userdb lookup(test1@mydomain123.com): Disconnected unexpectedly
08:18:07 lda: Fatal: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
lda: Error: userdb lookup(test1@mydomain123.com): Disconnected unexpectedly
lda: Fatal: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
auth: Fatal: master: service(auth): child 31229 killed with signal 11 (core dumped)
```

#### /var/log/dovecot-info.log [NO errors]

```
Aug 02 10:22:24 aauth-worker(31671): Info: passwd(test1@mydomain123.com,myip): unknown user 
Aug 02 10:22:24 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<test1@mydomain123.com>, method=CRAM-MD5, rip=myip, lip=123.123.123.123, mpid=31673, session=<my session>
```

#### /var/log/dovecot-debug.log [NO errors,BASE64 decoded]

```
auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=0)
auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    1   CRAM-MD5    service=smtp    nologin lip=123.123.123.123 rip=myip
auth: Debug: client passdb out: CONT    1   <2224380703338822.1470101122@123.123.123.123>
auth: Debug: client in: CONT    1   test1@mydomain123.com [some hash..] (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)
auth: Debug: password(test1@mydomain123.com,myip): passdb doesn't support credential lookups
auth-worker(31687): Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth
auth-worker(31687): Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libdriver_mysql.so
auth-worker(31687): Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libdriver_sqlite.so
auth-worker(31687): Debug: sql(test1@mydomain123.com,myip): query: SELECT username AS user,password FROM mailbox WHERE username = 'test1@mydomain123.com' AND active='1'
auth: Debug: password(test1@mydomain123.com,myip): Credentials: [some hash]
auth: Debug: client passdb out: OK  1   user=test1@mydomain123.com
```

#### SQL log [NO errors, but no query about mailbox.Why???]

```
 /usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 10.1.16-MariaDB (MariaDB Server). started with:
    Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: (null)
    Time                 Id Command    Argument
            2 Connect   mymaildb@localhost as anonymous on mymaildb
                2 Query SELECT username AS user,password FROM mailbox WHERE username = 'test1@mydomain123.com' AND active='1'
                3 Connect   mymaildb@localhost as anonymous on mymaildb
                3 Query SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='mydomain123.com' AND active = '1'
                4 Connect   mymaildb@localhost as anonymous on mymaildb
                4 Query SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='mydomain123.com' AND active = '1'
                3 Query SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='test1@mydomain123.com' AND active = '1'
                3 Query SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='test1@mydomain123.com' AND active = '1'
```

#### SQL log(An OK email to root)

```
5 Connect   mymaildb@localhost as anonymous on mymaildb
            5 Query SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='mydomain123.com' AND active = '1'
            6 Connect   mymaildb@localhost as anonymous on mymaildb
            6 Query SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='mydomain123.com' AND active = '1'
            7 Connect   mymaildb@localhost as anonymous on mymaildb
            7 Query SELECT username AS user,password FROM mailbox WHERE username = 'test1@mydomain123.com' AND active='1'
            7 Quit  

            5 Query SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='root@localhost' AND active = '1'
            8 Connect   mymaildb@localhost as anonymous on mymaildb
            8 Query SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = 'localhost' and alias.address = CONCAT('root', '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'
            9 Connect   mymaildb@localhost as anonymous on mymaildb
            9 Query SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = 'localhost' and alias.address = CONCAT('@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'
            5 Query SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='root' AND active = '1'
            5 Query SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='@localhost' AND active = '1'
            9 Query SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = 'localhost' and alias.address = CONCAT('@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'
            5 Query SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='localhost' AND active = '1'
            6 Query SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='localhost' AND active = '1'

            8 Quit  
            6 Quit  
            9 Quit  
            5 Quit
```

Comment: Do you see delivery attempts in `/var/log/maillog`

Comment: I have added logs.Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your `/var/log/dovecot.log`, your `lda` (local delivery agent) cannot lookup recepient's name from database. So, probably, your issue is `SQL` related. Also I see that you are using `anonymous` user for lookups (bad practice btw). So first of all you need to ensure that `anonymous` user is allowed to perform **all** required queries. Also you may check your `SQL` server's logs for errors and post it here (if any).

Comment: I noticed that /usr/libexec/dovecot/auth crashed while I trying to send an email to virtual users. Maybe I should rebuild it.

Comment: I have rebuilt it. Everything seems fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: PS:Dovecot 2.2.10 Failure (Maybe it has a bug) Dovecot 2.2.25 Success

Comment: A small problem: I can't use virtual email user sent email to myself. Such as test1@mydomain123.com to test1@mydomain123.com